# How can I use static IP addresses for outbound https(s) without Fixie?

Tags: heroku, https, proxy

Fixie is an addon that provides static IP addresses for outbound HTTP and HTTPS requests. However, their pricing is quite harsh; $1,999/mo per app for my use-case. I have a lot of outbound HTTPS requests.

How do these outbound proxies work? Is there an open-source alternative or commercial alternative that I can self-host on for example AWS?

Answer (score 1):

For fixed Static IP address you can use the [EIP (Elastic IP address)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

It not only fulfills what you are seeking, i.e fixed client/host address but also provides you with a lot of flexibility. Eg: some key points:

1. Once provisioned, the address is associated with your account.So, you basically own it to use it with any instance you like.
2. You can associate and disassociate with an EC2 instance, for a cheap way to implement fault tolerance, by associating with a different instance if one instance fails.
3. You can associate with a NAT instance to provide proxy functionality.

Comment: Does Google have a version of this?

Comment: By the loos of it EIP just gives the fixed IP. You'd need a service like nginx running to route the traffic through it?